# hierarchical html listbox with mimicking file explorer level folding

Tags: jquery, html, explorer, hierarchical

i'm looking for a technique to adapt a html listbox to hierarchical content with an unlimited number of levels ( const > 1 would be sufficient ). hierarchy levels should be collapsible as in the usual file explorer views. the html listbox behaviour should be preserved / mimicked as comprehensively as possible. do you have a hint on where to find or how to implement this ? jquery solutions are fine.

firefox 3.5+, ie 8+, safari 5 must be supported; opera 11, chrome 9 would be nice.

as far as i understand the issue, listbox contents are rendered inside their own browser window sporting none of the standard window adornments. a hint on how to obtain a handle on this window in js would be a sufficient starting point, as well as correcting me in case i misconceived the browser behaviour.

thanks in advance for your efforts,

best regards,

carsten

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to make a tree, where each node is a Listbox?  Would selecting an item in a given list open a new branch?  (Some explanation or rough sketches would help.)

Comment: i'm aiming at a listbox containing a tree view with collapsible subtrees. the subtree guard (the optgroup element in for standard html listboxes) would be enhanced with an explorer-style +/- symbol to expand/collapse its content items. multiple levels should be supported (which cannot be implemented using optgroups) and the whole tree should be contained in a single listbox.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what you're trying to accomplish - it's basically a tree-shaped selection mechanism, right?  The options are hierarchical in nature.  So, yeah you can't use an actual `<select />` tag - you'll need to mimic it and use JS to set a hidden value somewhere based on a user click...  Hope it works out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [JStree](http://www.jstree.com/demo) before and found it relatively easy to work with and solidly built.  It has a few built-in themes you can use that mimic file explorers.

It uses a variety of data sources, including support for AJAX dynamic updates.  If your tree isn't too large, though, an HTML nested list is an ideal source for accessibility (no JS, screen-readers, robots will all have something to look at).

You can put pretty much whatever you want in each node, including listboxes or other form elements.

I'm not very clear on what you're trying to do, though (see comment above)...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/